# Dcucumber.options, how to have multiple tags

Tags: maven, cucumber-jvm

I am trying run cucumber tests using maven with following command

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tag @debug1"
```

This command works fine, however if i try something like following, i get error

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tag @debug1 @debug2"
```

Is there a way to pass in multiple tag names with cucumber run-time options?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

- To run scenarios with `@debug1` and `@debug2`:

**Old version of Cucumber-jvm:**

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @debug1 --tags @debug2"
```

**Actual version of Cucumber-jvm:**

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags '@debug1 and @debug2'"
```

- To run scenarios with `@debug1` or `@debug2`:

**Old version of Cucumber-jvm:**

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @debug1,@debug2"
```

**Actual version of Cucumber-jvm:**

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags '@debug1 or @debug2'"
```

Comment: On passing this command. will it take as "AND" of tags?? i mean "@debug1 AND @debug2".?

`mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @debug1,@debug2"`

Answer (score 24):

In Cucumber 6, property name has changed. Use:

```
mvn verify -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@debug1 or @debug2"
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Does this exist within their documentation? I am unable to find it, would love it if you could throw a link with their console commands for cucumber 6.

EDIT: Found this a minute after posting my question
https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#tags
but wondering if there's a list of all the available jvm commands for cucumber6?

Comment: THANK YOU. I've been searching for this answer and couldn't find the solution. Even ChatGPT does not know this. I don't understand why they keep changing this stuff and making it difficult for us.

Comment: Note that this works for Cucumber 7 as well.

Answer (score 8):

For me what was working with **surefire plugin**:

```
mvn clean test -D"cucumber.filter.tags=@tag1 or @tag2"
```

When I tried with this version:

```
mvn clean test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="not @MyTag"
```

I got this exception:

```
io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: Failed to parse 'cucumber.filter.tags' with value '"not @MyTag"'
Caused by: io.cucumber.tagexpressions.TagExpressionException: Tag expression '"not @MyTag"' could not be parsed because of syntax error: expected operator
```

Comment: If it's an another  question, please don't add it as an answer.

Comment: It is not a question. I provided an answer in case of using surefire plugin, since the mentioned answers were not working in my case. The additional exception could be a good clue when you provide the parameter on some way, and there is no exception or error message just simply the plugin not running the tests.

Comment: This worked for failsafe plugin as well  `mvn clean verify -P acceptanceTests -D"cucumber.filter.tags=@get or @post"`   . I am using `cucumber 6.9.1` with `junit5`

Answer (score 3):

Little late to the party, but I am using something like:

```
mvn test -D tags="debug1 and debug2"
```

I am on Cucumber 2.4.

The `@` symbol is optional. You can use a `tags` Maven property. And you can use boolean logic to hook up multiple tags - [official docs](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#tags).

Reduces the amount of typing little bit.

Answer (score 2):

I using this commandline to run multiple tags

```
mvn test  -Dcucumber.options="--tags '@tag1 or @tag2' --plugin io.qameta.allure.cucumber4jvm.AllureCucumber4Jvm --plugin rerun:rerun/failed_scenarios.txt"
```

Cucumber version 4.2.6

Comment: I use 4.2.7 and receive this error **Unknown lifecycle phase ".options=--tags '@TC_3'". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or
<plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>**

Answer (score 2):

for version 6.10.2 Cucumber and Junit 4.12

```
 mvn test "-Dcucumber.filter.tags= (@Tag1 or @Tag2) and not @Tag3"
```

where "or" is equal to "and".... for no reason (thanks Cucumber...)

Answer (score 1):

for cucumber 6 use: mvn clean test -D"cucumber.filter.tags=@smoke or @dev"

for cucumber 4 use: mvn clean test -D"cucumber.options.tags=@smoke or @dev"

Comment: this worked on my side

Answer (score 0):

In cucumber v5.X, only `mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags '@debug1 or @debug2'"`
is supported and working.
`mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags '@debug1 and @debug2'"` is not working and either scenarios won't get executed

Answer (score -1):

`mvn clean verify -D tags="tagName"`