# Is it possible to include and exclude via tags on the same karate command line

Tags: karate

We can select multiple scenario's by including the following on the command line:
-Dcucumber.options="--tags @S1,@S2,@S6"

And if I want to exclude @S6 I can with:
-Dcucumber.options="--tags ~@S6"

But if I want to include @S1, @S2 and exclude @S6 all tags are ignored with:
-Dcucumber.options="--tags @S1,@S2,~@S6"

and all tags are also ignored if I try to double up on the options with:
-Dcucumber.options="--tags @S1,@S2" -Dcucumber.options="--tags ~@S6"

Is there a command line way to include and exclude in the one command line?

The reason I would like to do this is to run all of a type of test but exclude tests that use some external system that may be down temporarily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: Turns out I was not fully aware of the difference between AND and OR in the Cucumber world. This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34543352/143475) and [this article](https://testingneeds.wordpress.com/2015/09/15/junit-runner-with-cucumberoptions/) was a good reference, look for "Logical OR" and "Logical AND":

so to run S1 `OR` S2 `AND NOT` S3

```
mvn test -Dkarate.options="--tags @S1,@S2 --tags ~@S3"
```

Using the Java (or `Runner`) API, just use commas for OR and separate strings for AND:

```
Results results = Runner.path("classpath:com/myco/some.feature")
            .tags("@S1,@S2", "~@S3")
            .parallel(5);
```

For *really* advanced cases, also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67224240/143475

Comment: I think there may be a couple of bugs in here.
Bug One:
The runner and the command line don't run the same tests for the same tags in demo.
eg 
For mvn clean test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @smoke,~@fire" -Dtest=TagsRunner
command line results are all four scenarios are run
For mvn clean test -Dtest=TagsSmokeNotFireRunner
results are only feature 1, scenario 1 is run

second bug
Will work on a project for that. I think there is an issue with having two include tags and an exclude tag. As per the original question I think this then ignores all tags.

Comment: maybe. maybe not. only one way to be sure: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: @TimFeltham big thanks. hope the edited answer clarifies.