# karate api testing - How to read tag names from command line to feature file

Tags: karate

**karate api testing - How to read tag names from command line to feature file**

**My feature file**

Feature: validating tag name reading from maven command line

Background:

Given url baseURL

When param validation = **I want to read tagname here**

Then method get

Then status 200

@com_status @all @**I want to read tagname here**

Scenario Outline: Testing tag input scenarios

- print **I want to read tagname here**

**Command -** mvn clean test -Dtest=Runner -DargLine="-Dkarate.env=dev" -Dcucumber.options="--tags @com_status"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. Tags are designed to be passed on the command line to filter scenarios to run - and cannot be retrieved within a test. You can retrieve the tag of a `Scenario` though: https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-tags

You can try using `karate.properties` or something similar to retrieve what was passed on the command-line: https://github.com/intuit/karate#dynamic-port-numbers

Command:

```
mvn clean test -DcustomName=foo
```

Feature:

```
* def customName = karate.properties['customName']
```

Feel free to contribute this feature if you think it is important.

EDIT - update in 1.1.0 onwards, there is a new feature "Exvironment Tags" that may solve what is being asked for here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#environment-tags

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50693388/143475

Also for advanced filtering using tag values when the tag is in the form `@name=value1,value2`, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67219165/143475

Comment: Really thanks a lot for your reply, Sure I will try my best

Comment: i am using something like mvn clean test -DcustomName=foo, to get the tagValue to execute. But how to execute that particular tag value from Runner.path()

Comment: @NagulanS the last link has an example. also please read the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#parallel-execution

Comment: @PeterThomas the link only has examples of tags like @ s1, @ s2, @ s3. I want to know how to run specific tag values. Like example there is a tag: @ User=student, teacher. Now I want a way to run all @ user tagged scenarios with value student and all @ user tagged scenarios with value teacher separately.

Comment: can u please take a look at this question again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77673903/how-to-run-scenarios-with-specific-tag-values-in-karate. It explains in detail my doubt. Even if its a repatitve question by any chance, can u give me an example code, cos I didn't find any in the docs.

Comment: @NagulanS you may be looking for this then: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67219165/143475

Answer (score 1):

Below is the command to execute the tag from the command line in Karate Api automation testing.

```
mvn test -DargLine="-Dkarate.env=e2e" "-Dkarate.options=--tags @user_management_get_vender_types"
```