# Using tags to exclude group of features

Tags: karate

We are using tags to be able to group features and senarios. For example, we have something like:

```
@jira=123 
Scenario: test scenario 1
...

@jira=456
Scenario: test scenario 2, known failure
...

Scenario: test scenario 3, new feature
```

Now, we are hoping to run test that are not tagged with @jira=123 or @jira=456. Because we have many features and scenarios tagged with the @jira=somevalue, it is impractical to add them all. So I am looking for a way to be able to exclude anything tagged with @jira. I tried ~@jira and "~@jira=" but no luck.
Looking at the following junit case:

[TagTest.java#testToString()](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/789e8c703b2359a6fd40f284c5ca81e475fa5054/karate-core/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/core/runner/TagTest.java#L34)

Which is using "@foo=" as a tag, but was not able to find an example. Is there a way to exclude a group of scenarios tagged by @jira, regardless of the tag value ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we haven't documented this well but this question here can be a start. Karate actually supports a mini expression language for tags.

Have a look at this test for some options: [`TagsTest.java`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/89179842ff7260b1bc299f96d0dda9ddf6afcd2e/karate-core/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/core/TagsTest.java#L59)

And this should work for your requirement, do confirm in the comments ! Yes just use the string below where you would normally put `@jira` etc.

`!valuesFor('@jira').isPresent`

One more important point. When you use the special expression language, any AND or OR complexity has to be managed within the single expression that you pass into the `tags` option. Only one expression is needed and the use of comma-separated values or multiple values for the `tag` parameter is not applicable.

For example:

To select scenarios that have values for either the `@fail` tag or the `@bad` tag (note the use of the JS `||` (OR) operator):

```
valuesFor('@fail').isPresent || valuesFor('@bad').isPresent
```

And to select any scenario that has values for the `@fail` tag and where the `@smoke` tag is present (without values, just the plain tag and no `=` part):

```
valuesFor('@fail').isPresent && anyOf('@smoke')
```

And yes, you can use the "expression language" on the command-line i.e. within the `karate.options` or as the `--tags` or `-t` option to the stand-alone JAR: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72054253/143475

Comment: I think I am still missing something. May be I was not clear in my question. We are looking to run those from command line, just like we pass the tags filter when invoking maven:

```
mvn test "-Dkarate.options=--tags @jira classpath:features"
```

Answer (score 2):

The tag value is the whole string, even if it contains a `=` and you may assume there is key and a value.
But you could consider to use multiple tags, they are allowed.

So, in your case, I would use something like:

```
@jira=123
@jira

Scenario: test scenario 1
...

@jira=456
@jira
Scenario: test scenario 2, known failure
```

And the you can use the `~@jira` to exclude all the `@jira` scenarios.
This will allow you to still reference the single `@jira=123` when needed.

Comment: Which means I have to use the "@jira" twice. Once for "@jira", and the second time for "@jira=123"

This is not what I was looking for