# How can I run tests with name value tags?

Tags: tags, karate

I saw your answer for this question which gave me hope:

[Using tags to exclude group of features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67218766/using-tags-to-exclude-group-of-features)

We have a practice of tagging tests that fail due to defect so we can run them in a failed group and have the tests that are supposed to pass in another group.  This allows us to quickly review a regression run to find new failures, not the failures that are pushed off for the next sprint.

We tag our scenarios like this where the value is the defect id:

```
@FAIL=DE12345
Scenario: API Scenario
```

Our Junit Test runner was updated based on the feedback on the other post to run all tags that contain the name in the tag:
https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/89179842ff7260b1bc299f96d0dda9ddf6afcd2e/karate-core/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/core/TagsTest.java#L59

```
Results results = Runner.path("classpath:com/company/tests")
                .tags("valuesFor('@FAIL').isPresent")
                .parallel(5);
```

Nothing runs when I do this. It looked like it was what I was hoping for but I think I may be doing something wrong.  I tried this in 0.9.6 and 1.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the few questions where people report not being able to get it to work has been frustrating. I've asked every one to follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - but no luck.

Maybe you will be the one to "break the chain". If we can get a clear way to replicate, we can fix it. So please consider contributing some time to make the framework better.

Comment: I will.  I've submitted in the past a minimal test.  This helps me out and helps the community.

Comment: The issue turns out is when you combine this tag language with the AND and OR clauses to run specific tests with different tags.  The simple case works. Issue posted here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1720