# How to run scenarios with specific tag "values" in karate

Tags: spring-boot, command-line-arguments, karate

```
@two=foo,bar
Scenario:
* def tagNames = karate.tags
* def tagValues = karate.tagValues


@two=foo
Scenario:
* def tagNames = karate.tags
* def tagValues = karate.tagValues

@two=bar
Scenario:
* def tagNames = karate.tags
* def tagValues = karate.tagValues
```

How to specify the tag value as arguments in command line execution in karate.

Edit 1:

It seems like there was a confusion. My doubt was not around tag names. I can run karate for a specific tag by

> mvn test -Pkarate -Dkarate.options="--tags @tagname"

But was wondering how to do it with tag values like in the above example the tag "two" has two values.

Edit 2:

Below is my karate executor code in java.

```
Results results = Runner.path("classpath:karate/features").tags("~ignore").parallel(FIVE);
```

Comment: for handling tag values, here is a reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67219165/143475

Comment: Thanks got it.
ANSWER: mvn test -Pkarate -Dkarate.options="--tags valuesFor('@ two').isAnyOf('bar')"