# Can you use wildcard characters with tags to get all matching tags

Tags: karate

I'm wondering if you can use wildcard characters with tags to get all tagged scenarios/features that match a certain pattern.

For example, I've used 17 unique tags on many scenarios throughout many of my feature files.  The pattern is "@jira=CIS-" followed by 4 numbers, like @jira=CIS-1234 and @jira=CIS-5678.

I'm hoping I can use a wildcard character or something that will find all of the matches for me.

I want to be able to exclude them from being run, when I run all of my features/scenarios.
I've tried the follow:

--tags ~@jira

--tags ~@jira*

--tags ~@jira=*

--tags ~@jira=

Unfortunately none have given my the results I wanted.  I was only able to exclude them when I used the exact tag, ex. ~@jira=CIS-1234.  It's not a good solution to have to add each single one (of the 17 different tags) to the command line.  These tags can change frequently, with new ones being added and old ones being removed, plus it would make for one real long command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. First read this - there is this un-documented expression-language (based on JS) for advanced tag selction based on the `@key=val1,val2` form: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67219165/143475

So you should be able to do this:

```
valuesFor('@jira').isPresent
```

And even (here `s` will be a string, on which you can even do JS regex if you know how):

```
valuesFor('@jira').isEach(s => s.startsWith('CIS-'))
```

Would be great to get your confirmation and then this thread itself can help others and we can add it to the docs at some point.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific, I'm using maven and bamboo to run the command line like "clean test -Dthreads=1 -Dkarate.env=myenv "-Dkarate.options="--tags ~@ignore --tags ~jira classpath:features"".  This example is showing through code.  That's not what I want, I want to be able to do this on the command line.  Or does that feature not exist?  I also haven't upgraded to 1.0 yet, I'm on 0.9.2.

Comment: @CoreySnow you CAN use that text as-is in place of where you use `~@foo` try it please. yes it is ugly and it is actual JS code, but it should work

Comment: it's working, well partly.  How can I combine it to be both ~@ignore and ~@jira?  I've tried a few combinations, but it hasn't produced the results I need.  I tried "-Dkarate.options=--tags ~@ignore --tags !valuesFor('@jira').isPresent classpath:features".  It seems like --tags !valuesFor('@ignore').isPresent, !valuesFor('@jira') doesn't work either.

Comment: @CoreySnow you can't mix the "old" and "new" notations. so try: `not('@ignore') && !valuesFor('@jira').isPresent` - if that doesn't work, I give up :) please contribute code 

Comment: Tthat sadly didn't work either.  It didn't run anything with @ignore, but it still ran the ones with @jira=CIS-1234, which is weird.  Could it be because we have @KarateOptions(tags = { "~@ignore" } hard coded in our ParallelTest.java?

Comment: I tried "!valuesFor('@ignore').isPresent && !valuesFor('@jira').isPresent" and that actually both. I can't seem to find a combination to work and I feel like we're right there

Comment: @CoreySnow I'm lost and as I said I give up, isn't it working as you asked. it is plain JS so are you saying you want `not('@ignore') || !valuesFor('@jira').isPresent` try that. over and out.

Comment: Thank you @PeterThomas for everything.  While what you have said words, at least for all the scenarios we have tagged with a jira number, I can't get it to work with ignore.  I've tried every command line option I can think of, with and without making changes in our ParallelTest which has karate options set to ignore.  I'm just going to use ignore and type out all 17 jira numbers, dirty but it works

Comment: @CoreySnow I'm a little backed up, hence the hurried replies. ideally we would love for you to help fix the code (try to get help if needed) we seem to be close and missing some edge cases. note that you are one of the first to request advanced usage like this

Comment: No worries @PeterThomas, I appreciate all the help.  We decided to change the way we tag, and instead of jira=CIS-1234, we're tagging the scenarios twice, once with jira and then again with CIS-1234.  With that we're sending --tags ~@ignore --tags ~@jira on the command line and it's working perfectly!