# How to run multiple tags with OR, AND using Cucumber

Tags: java, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I'm trying to run multiple tags in a project using old Cucumber-jvm.
Basically what I need is to run a test that has 2 tags (p.e. @Chicken @Number1 ) and after that run other test (p.e. @Rice @Number2).
I'm trying to do with maven using:

```
mvn clean test -Dcucumber.options="(--tags @Chicken --tags @Number1),(--tags @Rice --tags @Number2"
```

but that definitely not worked well.
I trying using executable jar too using this method:

```
java -jar C:\Desktop\test.jar C:\Desktop\features --glue com.test classpath:features --tags (@Chicken --tags @Number1),(@Rice --tags @Number2)
```

but that didn't work either.
Is there any way I can do it or do I need to separate in some way this to work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dcucumber.options, how to have multiple tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34538571/dcucumber-options-how-to-have-multiple-tags)

Comment: No because for my question I'm trying to using OR, AND in the same script, not only AND or OR independently.

Comment: The  main point of the duplicate is that you should have a single `--tags` with the desired expression in single quotes. You can use parentheses for more complex expressions, see https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#tag-expressions