# gradle Dcucumber options. how to run several tags

Tags: gradle, cucumber, cucumber-java

Java, Gradle, Cucumber

I have 2 scnearios:

1) auth

2) wallet-mgmt

In 1st scenarion I get tokenId and I need to use it in 2nd scenario

I want to run this 2 scenarios by tag in 1 task

For run 1 scenario with one tag i use. I run it from IDEA:

```
gradle -Dcucumber.filter.tags='(@auth)' cucumber
```

I found this but it doesn't helped me - [Dcucumber.options, how to have multiple tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34538571/dcucumber-options-how-to-have-multiple-tags)

 Next i tried several variatns, example:

```
gradle -Dcucumber.filter.tags='(@auth)', '(@wallet-mgmt)' cucumber
```

but everytime smth is wrong

 How I can run it together? Thanks a lot! Have a nice day

Comment: The same way you would in maven.    See here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34538571/dcucumber-options-how-to-have-multiple-tags  `-Dcucumber.filter.tags="@debug1 or @debug2"`